# Robots.txt, php.ini, .htaccess, etc

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

This will be my first website, so I am completely new to all of this.

I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere, as to whether or not I should disallow configuration files like `/php.ini` or hidden files like `/.htaccess`?

I have read elsewhere on ProWebmasters that we should not `disallow: /*.js$` or `/*.css$`, but those answers were almost a decade old!

And what about stuff like `/includes` or `/includes/connect_to_database.php`?

Even Google's own document regarding `robots.txt` do not seem to cover this stuff. Is anybody aware of informative resources somewhere on the web relating to this stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to deny access to those files for robots or humans ?

> I have read elsewhere on ProWebmasters that we should not disallow: /*.js$ or /*.css$, but those answers were almost a decade old!

Never disable js and css files because google crawls them to render the urls.

> I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere, as to whether or not I should disallow configuration files like /php.ini or hidden files like /.htaccess?

You can disallow access to theses files, example in your .htaccess file to prevent access to the .htaccess file itself :

```
# Deny access to .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

For `/includes` or `/includes/connect_to_database.php` etc ... you can also manipulate .htaccess :

[If you choose to modify your httpd.conf file to solve this and you have multiple Options directives, then you must add a - or a + before each directive. Example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing)

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: i thought the whole point of `robots.txt` is to determine what is **indexed,** not what is crawled?

Comment: Google will still crawl and sometimes index urls even if there's instructions not to in robots.txt. The only way to prevent indexing is either .htaccess / htpsswd /  meta robots noindex etc...

Comment: ok, but you didnt really address my point. isnt the purpose of `robots.txt` ***indexing*** and not crawling?

Comment: Robots.txt is not a file aimed at indexing. It's a set of rules for robots/crawlers. 
For indexing you can submit url to the search console or use a sitemap.

Comment: or `<meta name='robots' content='index'>` right?

Comment: Google is not the only search engine out there, nor the only web pages crawler. There are others. And some will explicitly **not** follow the content of `robots.txt`, because they deem it important to collect all pages for historical archival. You may agree or disagree with that, but it exists, showing that `robots.txt` contains recommendation/suggestion, without any mean to enforce them.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek good point